# Generate Matriculation Number

Tags: oracle

Involvement: Oracle database and C# (Windows Forms)

I have a two separate database tables: Faculty and Department, each having name and numeric ID Column. To assign a matriculation number to each student record added to my STUDENT_REC table, I used the last 2 digits of year, faculty_id and department_id using C# code to fetch records from my Faculty and Department tables.

Example: 18- year is constant, 10- faculty of science and 38 - department of geology are selected from combo box and automatically generates the number in my Windows Form ( matric number will be 181038. But now I want it to add 001/002/etc to every added record.

How do I add such serial numbering to the end of each number being unique and distinct to EACH department...serially?

Comment: You want a `sequence` to generate the serial numbering. I'm not sure where you're concatenating the year / faculty_id / department_id - a trigger maybe? But you'd just add the sequence to the end. See e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171919/133052

Comment: Get the last serial number used per department with `SELECT MAX(MOD(mariculationNumber, 1000))  AS lastNum FROM STUDENT_REC WHERE DepartmentId = :mid`.

Comment: I've edited my post, I didn't allow me to add images. Sorry I hope it's clearer now.